# C# Class member validation without having Private members

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Is there a way to conduct error range checking in C# for class members, without Private members?

1)

For example here, I Need Private member for (less than/greater than checking).

```
public class PageModel
{
    private int page;
    public int Page
    {
        get => page;
        set
        {
            if (value < 0) { page = 0; }
            else page = value;
        }
    }
```

2)

If only have Public member, the get=> Page line gives SonarQube error

> Add a way to break out of this property accessor's recursion

```
public class PageModel
{
    public int Page
    {
        get => Page;
        set
        {
            if (value < 0) { Page = 0; }
            else Page = value;
        }
    }
```

Just curious if there is way to conduct data validation without private member. Are data annotations good method also? are they as safe as private members?

Comment: No, you may not have an auto-implemented property with auto-implemented getter and manually implemented setter. [Both have to be auto-implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#auto-implemented-properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question answered before OP's edit**

Property is not a field, it is just shorthand for:

```
private int <>_page;
public get_Page()
{
    return <>_page;
}

public set_Page(int value)
{
     <>_page = value;
}
```

So setting `Page` like that doesn't make any sense.

```
public int Page
{
    get => Page;
}
```

Answering your question, no, there is no way to get rid of additional field, because there is nothing to write to if you get rid of the field.

You would have to create a method such as

```
public int Page { get; set; }    
public void Validate()
{
    if(Page < 0)
       Page = 0;
}
```

But there are endless possibilities of doing it.

Comment: @ZorgoZ It implicitly explains that it is not possible to get rid of private field. I will expand...

Comment: @ZorgoZ I think it answers the question.

Comment: where would I call validate method, in constructor?

Comment: @jerrythomas38 That depends on how you structure your code, but constructor is one way of doing this. If you don't change values of properties after creating instance of your object then yes, constructor could be the right place.

Comment: hi @ZorgoZ , FCin would data annotations be a good option? any other methods?

Comment: whats safer data annotations or methods above?

Comment: @MattSmith If you are worried about which option to choose then please create a new question. Your question seems to be out of scope of this question.

Comment: hi @FCin well requester just asked